# How are byte variables stored in memory?

Tags: c#, memory, byte

I'm reading a book about C# ([Pro C# and the .NET 4 Platform by Andrew Troelsen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430225491)) and I've just read this paragraph:

> Changing the underlying type of an
>   enumeration can be helpful if you are
>   building a .NET  application that will
>   be deployed to a low-memory device
>   (such as a .NET-enabled cell phone or
>   PDA) and need to conserve memory
>   wherever possible.

Is it true that bytes use less memory? Aren't they stored on 4 bytes for performance reasons? I remember reading the latter somewhere but I can't find any info about it, not even in the C# specification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It isn't simple. As *variables* in a method, they are pretty much the same as `int`, so 4-byte; inside an array they are single-byte. As a field... I'd need to check; <s>I *guess* padding means they may be treated as 4-byte.</s> A `struct` with `sizeof` should reveal...

```
struct Foo {
    byte a, b, c;
}
static class Program {
    unsafe static void Main() {
        int i = sizeof(Foo); // <==== i=3
    }
}
```

Here `i` shows 3, so they are single-byte as fields, but (see comments by codymanix) additional padding may be needed when other types get involved - for example:

```
struct Foo
{
    byte a, b, c;
    int d;
}
```

is **8** bytes, due to the need of `d` to be aligned. Fun fun fun.

Comment: But it will be different if you have struct Foo { byte a; int b; }. Since b is int it needs to be aligned, so additional padding is inserted.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on the target platform. On "low-memory"-devices, the CLR may choose to pack them tightly, so it will save memory if you change the enumeration type.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is explicitly defined by the C# or even .NET specification. You should use the [`StructLayout` and `FieldOffset` attributes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922785) to specify exact memory layout.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
struct TestDByte
{
    public double a;
    public byte b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Bytes don't need to be aligned to work efficiently on x86 CPUs (larger units do, though). For other CPU architectures, things may work differently.