# Is it good to create wrapper struct for byte to represent char and small int?

Tags: c#, struct, type-conversion

In C# both integers and characters can be converted to byte:

```
byte b1 = (byte) 50;
byte b2 = (byte) '2';
```

However after conversion the information of the original type is lost. In the above example, b1 and b2 have the same value (50). By only looking at the value of b1 and b2, we have no way to tell if it used to represent an integer or a character.

You might be wondering why I care. I have a memory intensive application which maintains a table-like structure in memory. Different columns store value of different datatypes. Values are generally stored in large arrays within a column. I want to enjoy the memory advantage of byte since char in c# occupies two bytes and int occupies four (I know the value range is not an issue). However I need to know if the byte should be interpreted as a number or a char when I render the data to screen. Again in the above example, b2 should be displayed as "2" while b1 should be rendered as "50".

Here is the solution I came across:

```
    public struct ByteChar
    {
        public readonly byte Value;

        public ByteChar(char v)
        {
            Value = (byte) v;
        }

     /*
      * Define two implicit conversion operators so that ByteChar can be used seamlessly with char
      * ByteChar c = ‘1’; //char to byte char
      * char a = c; //ByteChar to char
      */
        public static implicit operator char(ByteChar v)
        {
            return (char)v.Value;
        }

        public static implicit operator ByteChar(char v)
        {
            return new ByteChar(v);
        }

       /*
        * When converting to string, treat the value as a char instead of a number
        */

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return ((char)Value).ToString();
        }

        public override bool Equals(Object obj)
        {
            return obj is ByteChar && this == (ByteChar)obj;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Value.GetHashCode();
        }

        public static bool operator == (ByteChar x, ByteChar y)
        {
            return x.Value == y.Value;
        }

        public static bool operator != (ByteChar x, ByteChar y)
        {
            return x.Value != y.Value;
        }
    }
```

Similarly I introduced ByteInt:

```
    public struct ByteInt
    {
        public readonly byte Value;

        public ByteInt(int v)
        {
            Value = (byte) v;
        }

     /*
      * Define two implicit conversion operators so that ByteInt can be used seamlessly with int
      * ByteInt i = 1; //int to ByteInt
      * int j = i; //ByteInt to int
      */
        public static implicit operator int(ByteInt v)
        {
            return (int)v.Value;
        }

        public static implicit operator ByteInt(int v)
        {
            return new ByteInt(v);
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value.ToString();
        }

        public override bool Equals(Object obj)
        {
            return obj is ByteInt && this == (ByteInt)obj;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Value.GetHashCode();
        }

        public static bool operator == (ByteInt x, ByteInt y)
        {
            return x.Value == y.Value;
        }

        public static bool operator != (ByteInt x, ByteInt y)
        {
            return x.Value != y.Value;
        }
    }
```

Now I think this good because not only us developer can tell what is being stored as byte, but also the compiler and the runtime: DoSomething (byte b), DoSomething (ByteChar b), DoSomething (ByteInt b) will be three different signatures.

My question is: is this a good way to solve my problem? Is there any bad thing about the above implementation? Have I missed any detail in the above implementation that could lead to potential pitfalls?

Comment: Are you sure that micro-optimizing memory usage is the best use of your development time? (Also, and more obviously, if you're working with `int`s that you know will always fit into the `byte` range, why are you not using the 1 byte integer data type called `byte`?)

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I can use byte for integers and only introduce ByteChar for char. However I personally feel that the code looks clearer if I introduce ByteInt as well. So anyone in the team reading the code will immediately realize what is being stored. But as I said you are right.

Comment: The only purpose I can find for `ByteInt` is that it takes some errors that could be detected at compile time if `byte` had been used and instead turns them into runtime errors. That's the opposite direction than most people strive for.

Comment: can you let me know what errors you are talking? (this the purpose of this post). And what about the ByteChar?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: From a semantic standpoint, having distinct integral types which behave as numbers (`x=y+z` will either yield arithmetically-correct results or throw an exception), as members of a wrapping algebraic group, or as "whatever is fastest", would be helpful, and I don't know any particular reason a .NET language couldn't implement such a thing (though it would have to guess how to classify external method parameters, fields, etc. declared elsewhere).  I doubt any user type could implement such a thing without adverse performance costs, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that you will save any significant amount of memory with this approach.

It is very likely that you will see reduced performance and additional complexity.

See: [How are byte variables stored in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358469/how-are-byte-variables-stored-in-memory)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am basically using very large arrays as the storage. So "int vs byte" makes a big difference because they are put into large arrays. The alignment impact can be ignored

Comment: @Xinchao If you are storing them in large arrays you will still need two different arrays (one for your ByteChar and one for your ByteInt). You could differentiate them them implicitly by design (e.g. byte[] numbers = new byte[0x1000]; byte[] chars = new byte[0x1000];).

Comment: @ MarkSturgill The table will have arbitrary number of columns. (e.g. there is a Column Collection). To implicitly differentiate them, as suggested by you, means I probably need to associate with each column  metadata describing the "true" type.

Comment: @Xinchao How are you planning on storing both ByteChar and ByteInt in a single array while maintaining the type differentiation?

Comment: @ MarkSturgill They are in different columns. Something like:
`List<IColumn> colCollection = new List<IColumn> (); `
`colCollection.Add(new Column<ByteChar>() );`
`colCollection.Add(new Column<ByteInt>() );`

Comment: If you're using Column<T> then you already have something to differentiate the content of your collection. There is no need for additional complexity. You could use Column<char> and store as a byte array internally. You could have derived classes called CharacterColumn. There are many (better) approaches that don't rely on convoluted constructs.